# Is it possible to throttle JAX-WS / JAX-RS services in WSO2AS?

Tags: jax-ws, wso2, throttling

I know you can throttle 'Services' (eg Axis2) in WSO2AS 4.2.1 but there are no such options for JAX-WS / JAX-RS 'Applications' in the WEB-UI. Will this feature be added in a future version or is there another way of achieving throttling?

Thanks,
Kai

Comment: I am also trying to find an answer for that! Have you managed to find out?

Comment: Unfortunately nothing yet - but it's not our focus right now.